# Is it possible to create a multi-server SharePoint farm in the DMZ without using a domain?

Tags: sharepoint, dns

I'm working with a client to plan the topology for a public facing SharePoint internet site.

The SharePoint installation will live in the client's DMZ and the plan is to use an existing SQL Server machine to host the SharePoint databases.

The problem is that there is no domain in the DMZ - and the client doesn't want to create one without going through the proper planning process.

As far as I understand, there is no way to configure a multi-server SharePoint farm without using a Domain Account to initially connect SharePoint Central Administration to SQL.

I'm pretty sure (and have tried this) that you can't use SQL Server authentication to connect the farm to SQL Server when first provisioning Central Administration using the Productions and Technologies Wizard.

My other option is a single server install, acknowledging that this limits our future growth if we ever need to add another WFE.

Thank you

Comment: Oh man, I am spoiled.  When I saw "DMZ", I thought "Downtown Militarized Zone". :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No. Mostly.](http://blogs.msdn.com/fooshen/archive/2007/02/01/installing-moss-without-ad.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible because it works this way here in the company I work.

We basically have an user account with the same name on the 2 servers (web front end server and SQL database server). This account has access to the database.